# Can't create new model object from import laravel excel data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel from Maatwebsite to import a .xlsx file with headers, the problem is when I try to import the file, laravel returns an error saying:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'confirmation_number' cannot be null
```

My controller

```
public function createLettersFromImport(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        Excel::import(new LetterImport, $request->file('file')->store('temp'));

        return redirect()->route('mailsender.index');
    }
}
```

My LetterImport.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Confirmation;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class LetterImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Confirmation([
            'confirmation_number'           => $row['confirmation_number'],
            'guest_name'                    => $row['guest_name'],
            'guest_address'                 => $row['guest_address'],
            'email'                         => $row['email'],
            'checkin'                       => $row['checkin'],
            'checkout'                      => $row['checkout']
        ]);
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

My Confirmation.php model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Confirmation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'confirmations';

    protected $fillable = ['confirmation_number', 'guest_name', 'guest_address', 'email', 'checkin', 'checkout'];
}
```

When I make dd($row) on LetterImport.php $row has data from the file .xlsx

[image]

But the error stills the same

[image]

My file to import:
[image]

Edit: I can successfully import .csv files with the same structure, but not .xlsx

Comment: In your import, one of the confirmation_number fields doesn't have a value. Consider creating a migration that alters the confirmation_number column to be nullable. This is not a Laravel error, this is a SQL error.

Comment: `dd($row)` only shows a **single row** that you're importing; you cannot rely on that to debug if `confirmation_number` is `null` or not. How many rows are you importing? Is your importer picking up a "phantom row" (sometimes the last row in an Excel file, even if completely empty, can still be included)? Either way, you need to handle this, like `'confirmation_number' => $row['confirmation_number'] ?? 0` (or similar)

Comment: It's just a row, I edited the post to upload an image of the file :) thank you for your comments

Comment: Yeah, your code looks perfectly fine; I suspect this is a phantom row thing; if it's picking up row 3 as being filled in (for reasons; Excel is ), then all fields would be `null`, and converting that to a Model would fail. If you wrap your code in a `try/catch`, you should be able to debug `$row` and see. Or you can try selecting row 3 in Excel and removing it (Right Click > Delete Row), then try re-importing. If that still doesn't work, we'll try to debug further.

Comment: Yes @TimLewis I just realized that was phantom row, I added `'confirmation_number' => $row['confirmation_number'] ?? 0` to my LetterImport.php and on the DB was a lot of registers on null, can you post it as answer? so I can accept it :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Laravel Excel is picking up "Phantom Rows". When you're entering data into Excel, if you hit "Enter", your cursor moves into an empty cell below your current row (vs hitting "Tab", which moves to the next Cell in the current row). When this happens, Excel inserts metadata into that Cell, which is likely being picked up as a filled in row in your import code. You have a couple ways to handle this:

1. Delete the Extra rows in your Excel File:

This one is simple; just select everything below the rows you want to import and `Right Click` > `Delete Rows`. That *should* clear out any metadata from those Cells/Rows, and on your next Import, should only target Cells/Rows that were actually filled in.

2. Import as a `.csv` file:

As you stated in your question, a `.csv` file worked fine. This is due to `.csv` being text-based, and empty rows would render as `,,,,,,,` (a bunch of Commas, with no values). It would be a lot more obvious that there is an extra row(s), and deleting them would be much easier.

3. Handle this in your Code:

This is a little trickier. An easy way to handle this is to `return null;` if all `row['properties']` values are `null`:

```
if ($row['confirmation_number'] === null && $row['guest_name'] === null) {
  return null;
}

return new Confirmation([
  'confirmation_number' => $row['confirmation_number'],
  // ...
]);
```

The syntax get's a little silly with multiple Columns you're checking, but the approach would work the same with a `foreach()` loop, for example:

```
$columns = ['confirmation_number', 'guest_name', 'guest_address', 'email', 'checkin', 'checkout'];

$allBlank = true;
foreach ($columns as $column) {
  // If _any_ column has a value, update `$allBlank` to `false`
  if ($row[$column] !== null) {
    $allBlank = false;
  }
}

// If `$allBlank` is `true`, you hit a phantom row; return `null`
if ($allBlank) {
  return null;
}

// All good; return a new `Confirmation`
return new Confirmation([
  'confirmation_number' => $row['confirmation_number'],
  // ...
]);
```

Also have a look at [Row Validation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html); this might be able to validate and ignore Phantom Rows by making each column value `required`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, as In Laravel-excel `ToModel` interface does not allow to use `Model::create`. So, I used `implements ToCollection` instead of `implements ToModel` and use foreach loop inside it. My error was resolved with that.